# Migrate or Import Blogger Posts into Facebook

Tags: facebook, import, migration, blogs, blogger

Is there any way to migrate/import my blogger posts into Facebook with images, dates, txt?

I know that FB removed the notes/import feature but there's got to be an api, tool, trick to do this?.?